# Is induced subgraph isomorphism easy on an infinite subclass?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-theory

Is there a sequence of undirected graphs $\{C_n\}_{n\in \mathbb N}$, where each $C_n$ has exactly $n$ vertices and the problem

> Given $n$ and a graph $G$, is $C_n$ an induced subgraph of $G$?

is known to be in class $\mathsf{P}$? (For example, when $C_n=K_n$, this is the NP-complete clique problem.)

Comment: Crosspost from http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/10576/

Comment: So $\{ C_n \}$ is part of the problem definition, $n$ is part of the input, and $G$ is part of the input?

Comment: @Andrew D. King: Yes.

Comment: What about if $C_n$ is a star (one central node connected to $n-1$ nodes that form an independent set)? to check, merely enumerate all nodes of degree $n-1$ in $G$, and check if the neighbors form an independent set.

Comment: @Suresh: There may be a vertex of degree larger than $n-1$, whose some $n-1$ neighbors form an independent set. Finding them is NP-complete.

Comment: think the answer is likely yes but the ${C_n}$ might be "contrived". consider the "near" [Induced subgraph isomorphism problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induced_subgraph_isomorphism_problem), NP-complete. basically every NP complete problem seems to have P subproblems for increasing size inputs. example: SAT and 2-SAT. to contrive the answer it might require mapping the problem onto SAT or some other "more standard" NP complete problem.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken your question was answered by [Chen-Thurley-Weyer-2008](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1427956) modulo parameterized complexity assumptions.

I didn't read the paper carefully yet, but as far as I understood, there is a dichotomy in the sense that if $C$ is finite then the problem is in $P$, but if $C$ has an infinite number of graphs then the induced subgraph isomorphism is $W[1]$ complete (Corollary 4, page 6).

Thus it seems that unless the first level $W[1]$ of the $W$ hierarchy collapses to $FPT$, there is no such an infinite class of graphs whose induced subgraph isomorphism is in $P$.

There is another interesting result stating that if $P\neq NP$ then there are classes for which the induced isomorphism is neither in $P$ nor $NP$ complete.